# Why redis hash name cannot contain an email address?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I'm able to set keys that contain an email address like `mario@mario.com` but I cannot set a hash that contains `@` character.
What are the characters allowed when setting a hash key?

[image]

Is is possible to set a hash key that contains an email?

Comment: First `DEL mario@mario.com` and then try to use `HSET` - the error tells you what you're doing wrong (i.e. trying to store a Hash in an existing String key)

Comment: This is embarrassing! I tried with a couple of different emails and also with some prefixes but didn't realize I had already all those keys. Thanks @ItamarHaber!

Comment: I run `FLUSHALL` whenever I'm in the cli... good dev practice, but really bad for production ;)

Comment: Yeah, great tip! Thanks @ItamarHaber :)